# Enabling Huge Pages on RHEL6 for Oracle 18C xe

Tags: rhel, oracle, huge-pages

I have been trying to switch from oracle AMM to ASMM huge pages. I have done the following changes on RHEL 6

Added following entry  in /etc/sysctl.conf ( as suggested by hugepages_setting.sh )

```
      vm.nr_hugepages=777
```

Added following entry in /etc/security/limits.conf

```
       oracle   soft   memlock    2831155
       oracle   hard   memlock    2831155
```

rebooted the server
changed oracle parameters memory_target, memory_max_target, sga_target, sga_max_target, use_large_pages to specific values.

After a database restart, I can see the following:

```
     [root@rheloracle ~]# grep -i huge /proc/meminfo
      AnonHugePages:         0 kB
      HugePages_Total:     777
      HugePages_Free:        8
      HugePages_Rsvd:        0
      HugePages_Surp:        0
      Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

And when I shutdown the database I could see the HugePages_Free is equal to HugePages_Total.

```
       [root@rheloracle ~]# grep -i huge /proc/meminfo
       AnonHugePages:         0 kB
       HugePages_Total:     777
       HugePages_Free:      777
       HugePages_Rsvd:        0
       HugePages_Surp:        0
       Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Looks like HugePage configuration at db level and o/s level are in sync and in use. But all the examples and documents (i have referred) indicate that HugePages_Rsvd should have a non zero value after enabling huge pages. But same is not happening in my case. Can you please suggest if I am missing something or it's normal to have HugePages_Rsvd 0.

(I am running oracle 18c xpress edition on RHEL6)

Answer (score 0):

You should see a value for Reserved Huge Pages only if the Oracle `PRE_PAGE_SGA` parameter is set to `FALSE` which I think was the default up to Oracle 11.

Since Oracle 12 you should see the following by default:

```
SQL> show parameter PRE_PAGE_SGA

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
pre_page_sga                         boolean     TRUE

$ grep HugePages_Rsvd /proc/meminfo
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
```